# table radio button alignment issue

Tags: html

i want to make table content look like as shown in pic:-

[image]

but i get content alignment issue as shown in  my code.

```html
<form class="abc" id="abc" action="/" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
   <div>
      <div class="wrapper-class">
         <span>
         <input type="radio" value="true" name="abc[status]" id="abc_status_true">
         <label for="abc_approve">Approve</label>
         </span>
         <span>
         <input type="radio" value="false" name="abc[status]" id="abc_status_false">
         <label for="abc_reject">Reject</label>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="submit">
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change from `span` tag to `div` tag, and display Submit button on the right by `display flex` as

```
.wrapper-class{
padding: 10px;
}
.form{
display:flex;
align-items: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```css
/*
.wrapper-class, .submit{
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
}
*/
.wrapper-class{
padding: 10px;
}
.form{
display:flex;
align-items: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form class="abc" id="abc" action="/" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
   <div class="form">
      <div class="wrapper-class">
         <div>
         <input type="radio" value="true" name="abc[status]" id="abc_status_true">
         <label for="abc_approve">Approve</label>
         </div>
         <div>
         <input type="radio" value="false" name="abc[status]" id="abc_status_false">
         <label for="abc_reject">Reject</label>
         </div>
      </div>
   
   <div>
      <input type="submit">
   </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: this code when i paste inside table column. result is not same. i am getting radio button and submit button all one by one

Comment: https://codepen.io/gasgfasdf/pen/PoNoWZW?editors=1010 this code here works different

Comment: You copy wrong location, need move css to css section instead of js seciton, here it correct one https://codepen.io/viethien/pen/MWyWpXK